# Doctrine2 query error in OneToMany relation

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

I've got a doctrine2 problem with a MySQL database:

I have a model `User` and a model `Documents`. Each `User` may have 0 or n `Documents`. Each `Document` is assigned to exactly one `User`. My models:

**User**

```
<?php

namespace Entity;

/**
* @Entity(repositoryClass="Entity\Repository\UserRepository")
* @Table(name="user")
*/
class User extends Object
{
    /**
    * @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy="UUID")
    * @Column(type="string", length=36)
    * @var string
    */
    protected $id;

    /**
    * @OneToMany(targetEntity="\Entity\Document", mappedBy="user")
    */
    private $documents;

    public function __construct($options = array())
    {
        $this->documents = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
    }
}
```

**Document**

```
<?php

namespace Entity;

/**
* @Entity(repositoryClass="Entity\Repository\DocumentRepository")
* @Table(name="document")
*/
class Document extends Object
{
    /**
    * @Id @Column(type="string")
    * @var string
    */
    protected $id;

    /**
    * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="\Entity\User", inversedBy="documents")
    * @JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    * @var User
    */
    private $user;
}
```

Now I want to get the `User` of a given `Document` ID. The SQL-query would be:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM `user` u
INNER JOIN `document` d ON d.user_id = u.id
WHERE d.id = 'mydocumentid'
```

But this does't work:

```
$user = $queryBuilder
        ->select('u.*')
        ->from('\\Entity\\User', 'u')
        ->innerJoin('\\Entity\\Document', 'd', \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::ON, 'd.user_id = u.id')
        ->where('d.id = :documentId')
        ->setParameter('documentId', 'mydocumentid')
        ->setMaxResults(1)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getSingleResult();
```

Also the direct query doesn't work:

```
$query = $em->createQuery('
    SELECT
        u.*
    FROM
        Entity\\User u
    INNER JOIN
        Entity\\Document d ON d.user_id = u.id
    WHERE
        d.id = "mydocumentid"
');
```

Could you please help me to get this run?

**Error message**

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 66 near 'd ON d.user_id': Error: Identification Variable \Entity\Document used in join path expression but was not defined before.
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using:

```
->innerJoin('\\Entity\\Document', 'd', \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::ON, 'd.user_id = u.id')
```

Try using this:

```
->innerJoin('u.documents', 'd', \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::ON, 'd.user_id = u.id')
```

This is because Doctrine needs to know to which field in `user` the `documents` have to be joined. Knowing the field Doctrine will fetch the target entity and that way Doctine directly knows the class.

Comment: Thank you Mats. But this throws other errors. My setup is a bit more complex then showed here. Maybe there is something wrong somewhere else. I found another solution to solve it and cannot spend more time now to get it run the right way. But maybe your answer helps someone with a similar question. Thank you again!